# Pixel fragments after rendering only after adjustment clips that highlight a little area in the video

Tags: render

I used adjustment clips in some videos to highlight areas in videos by darkening the background.
Up until now I have never had any problems.
After rendering the video there show up some pixel fragments in the video right after the adjustment clip with the highlight effect.
I also used adjustment clips to create little arrows but they work perfectly fine and no fragments show up after the arrows.
So there are fragments only after the highlighting adjustment clips.
When I delete these specific adjustment clips, the fragments also dissapear.
Can anybody help me with that?
I added this picture of the fragments I have been talking about
Thank you in advance for your help!
[image: fragments]